# If Query result is big its creating multiple line

Tags: mysql, windows, oracle, notepad

I am exporting a oracle table data that has 165 rows into a delimited separated text file.

And then importing into mysql table by  Load Data Infile command.

Now the problem is, few row is too long so its created separate line in the text file

while import its creating problem.

my text file data is pipeline(|) separated and enclosed with double quote(").
And its on windows server

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you look at the file in a text editor which does automatic word wrap and then save the file?  The Oracle export should not wrap lines (unless you set some option telling it to...  I haven't used it in a looooong time).  Its output should be acceptable for an import unless you inadvertently modified it.

Comment: first i try to load, it was showing warnings that particular line not have enough value for all column. then i open that file in notepad

Comment: To get any help you will need to show the source and destination table schemas, the export command(s), the import command(s) and a sample of the line that didn't work the first time.  Does the table you are importing into have the same schema definition?

Comment: schema are same for both source and destination table.
i am exporting it from sql developer ,result set then right click and export.
mysql load query is   
LOAD DATA INFILE 'C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Test1.txt' INTO TABLE tmp_5
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
FIELDS OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'

Comment: Do your data has linebreaks in it?

Comment: it may have \N but i am enclosing it with double quote
i tried this if it is quoted then its not making any problem

Comment: This [link](http://gerardnico.com/wiki/database/oracle/sqlloader_carriage_return_in_text_field) might interest you! The loader would load line by line, and may end up with errors, when it interprets a new line I suppose.

Comment: my target table is mysql,i can't use sqlloader

Comment: @JimGarrison you are right
its nothing wrong with oracle export, i open it in different editor and every row in same line

Answer (score 0):

its nothing wrong with oracle export,

it is the problem with notepad

i open it in different editor and every row in same line